# Jquery ajax call to a xml file works in safari bot not in IE6, why?

Tags: jquery

Im trying to load an xml file using the jquery ajax function,it works fine in safari but fails in IE6,is there any reason why this the case?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="style.css" />
        <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
        <title>Reading XML with jQuery</title>
         <script>
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "sites.xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: function(xml) {
                        $(xml).find('site').each(function(){
                            var id = $(this).attr('id');
                            var title = $(this).find('title').text();
                            var url = $(this).find('url').text();
                            $('<div class="items" id="link_'+id+'"></div>').html('<a href="'+url+'">'+title+'</a>').appendTo('#page-wrap');
                            $(this).find('desc').each(function(){
                                var brief = $(this).find('brief').text();
                                var long = $(this).find('long').text();
                                $('<div class="brief"></div>').html(brief).appendTo('#link_'+id);
                                $('<div class="long"></div>').html(long).appendTo('#link_'+id);
                            });
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
         </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="page-wrap">
            <h1>Reading XML with jQuery</h1>
         </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks

Comment: what problems you see? is the response xml coming correctly in safari? if not try replacing url: "sites.xml" with url: "/sites.xml"

Comment: the response is coming fine in safari,no problems there. i tried changing the path like u suggested but no joy in IE6.its still the same,just blank.

Comment: i just googled and some one has quoted "IE has issues with the way jQuery handles XML on the local filesystem. If you upload the same code on a server it works without a problem." is this true??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two ideas for you:

1. I believe some browsers' xml implementations are case sensitive. make sure your `$(xml).find('site')` if the xml has `<Site>` or `<SITE>` it may not work.
2. if the sites.xml is a local file, you may have issues loading it with ajax. Try putting it on a webserver as manraj82 suggested

Comment: thanks for the answer,its weird but it worked when viewed from a web server in IE...  sites.xml is a local file[development machine],dont really understand why IE6 failed,has it got something to do with the mimetype??